Python's pyproj projection conversion not as accurate as projection conversion in QGIS
I am converting point data from EPSG 26706 to EPSG 26906.  The below code runs without error but does not use the most accurate transformation between the two datums and therefore I end up with a 2.5 m difference.  Whereas, if I do the conversion in QGIS I get an error less than 0.0005 meters. Is there a more accurate way to convert projections using python?  I have quite a few files that I need to convert. I am using pyproj 3.6.1 with Python 3.9.7
from pyproj import Proj, Transformer

def nad27utm_to_nad83utm6N(df):
  trans = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:26706", "EPSG:26906",always_xy=True)
  df["CoordsPrefX"],df["CoordsPrefY"] = trans.transform(df.CoordsOrigX,df.CoordsOrigY)
  df["CoordsPrefGridCode"]="EPSG 26906; UTMZ6N_NAD83"


  return df


Similar question seems to suggest missing files and this answer (on a another question) gives a way to diagnose & how to find out where to put the files.
